# Varying ID's, One JQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to use ID instead of something repeatable like class, just because of the way the plugin I'm calling works. So below, I am having to create two different functions in order to force the bootstrapValidator in a particular field upon clicking a checkbox. I can't use something like

```
'revalidateField', 'availmon[] || availtue[]'
```

but is there some other method or variable I can use so I'm not doing this same function 7x?

**[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/babnxecg/)** with all of the external resources attached for seeing what I'm actually doing.

```
$(function () {
    $('#checkallmon').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        $('#app').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'availmon[]');
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#checkalltue').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        $('#app').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'availtue[]');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".checkall").on('click', function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var validationRule = elem.data('validation-rule');
        elem.closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        $('#app').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', validationRule+'[]');
    });
});
```

And in the HTML you do it like this:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline preferred">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkallmon" class="checkall" name="availmon[]" data-validation-rule="availmon" value="open">Fully Available
</label>
```

Didn't try this, but it should work. So it's bound to a class (used your `checkall` class) and the function gets the validation rule from the data attribute `validation-rule`. So you just have to assign `checkall` as class and `data-validation-rule` with the name of the rule to any checkbox.

You could also use the `.attr('name')` to use the name as "rule", but in my opinion the data attribute is a much cleaner way.

I hope I understood your question in the right way.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you! Updated JSFiddle to see your work in action: http://jsfiddle.net/babnxecg/2/

Comment: I'm glad this helped you and nice to see it in action